# Browsing internet and using other applications during a distro upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, release-management

I'm upgrading from 16.04 to 17.10 and received the warning about closing applications to avoid losing data. Does this apply to web browsing and/or music streaming services?

Am I risking anything by using a browser or music streaming desktop client during upgrade?

Comment: There's no supported direct upgrade path from Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10 and so many indirect upgrades are often problematic. If you want to upgrade I recommend that you wait until [the release of 18.04.1 at the end of July](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule) for a *direct* upgrade from 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general it's not required to close applications before distro upgradation. But it's recommended because during upgradation process tons of libraries will be upgraded (mostly this happens as, first remove old one and then install uptated lib), and that may cause problems during application's runtime if it is using the library(s) that is going to be updated, which results in exception and data loss.

Answer (score 1):

When messages warn you about the potential loss of data, they typically refer to unsaved data in your current session. For example, if you're creating a new document, and you have several paragraphs of unsaved work, this could be lost if you don't save it, or have an autosaving feature set up to save your work every few minutes.

If you're worried about losing your music, browser settings and bookmarks, you're fine. These are things that are already persistent data, and therefore will not be list in an upgrade.